# How do I prevent a bookmark tassel from fraying?

Tags: books

My favorite notebook has a woven bookmark tassel that is prone to serious fraying:

[image]

My question is a simple one: how do I stop it from fraying?

A good solution can't visually interfere with the tassel, though. For instance, taping it would work, but would look ugly.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour some thin (!) cyanoacrylate glue (superglue) on the end of the tassel, at the point where it starts fraying. The tassel will absorb the glue; use just enough that the glue is spread along the full width and depth of the tassel. The glue must be thin enough for the capillary effect to work. CA gel is too thick.
The glue keeps the threads together and prevents further fraying. The only visible effect is a slight change in color.
I've used this on tassels and on e.g. luggage straps.

Answer (score 1):

**What you could do:**

- Burn the end of it slightly. This would make the end discolored, but would stop fraying and keep most of the color of the bookmark. This works if it is Nylon or similar.
- You could take a band, rubber or a hair band, and put it around the place of fraying, this would discourage more fraying and can look quite pretty.
- Braiding the fray and tying off the end also work. If you can braid with many strands this might help. But this may not work, as the strand are short.
- You can also get tapes in many colors. So if you wanted, you might find one that would match the tassel. Either way the fraying should be fixed as soon as possible, otherwise more fraying will continue.

Answer (score 0):

Use some plain nail polish, it might dry quite hard but it still stops it from fraying.